# How do I use a setAdapter or setCurrentItem with a scrollview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

So I recently replaced the my android.support.v4.view.ViewPager with android.widget.ScrollView in my layout file and then after that I also changed the code in my main activity onCreate. The problem is that I cannot use setAdapter and setCurrentItem with scrollview.

```
    View background = findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
    ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    scrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    scrollView.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Comment: yeah you can add it because it's scrollview it supports only one view  as child so you need to decide what is your requirement is, else you can also use recyclerview if it suits your needs

Comment: what is a recyclerview? I can seem to be able to add it to my res>layout file

Comment: if you have some need to display list like thing where you have multiple items to be displayed at the same it scrolls to see all the list you can use recyclerview. can be added to layout here is link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.htmlca

Comment: Im trying to have fragments that I can swipe up down left and right but I cant seem to have it swipe up. Not sure what to use for my layout file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete Idea You may need **GestureDetectorCompat** to detect the swipe in described directions and then use the data to detect the direction in motion and replace your current fragment in the main activity with your respective fragment and it can be any fragment you want based on swipe direction and also you can enable transition to make it look like it's getting scrolled in either direction.

here is a sample code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String DEBUG_TAG = "Debug";
GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(e1.getY() - e2.getY(), e2.getX() - e1.getX()));

            if (angle > -45 && angle <= 45) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
                //here open your fragment right to left
                replaceFragments(FragmentRightToLeft.getInstance());
                return true;
            }

            if (angle >= 135 && angle < 180 || angle < -135 && angle > -180) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
                //here open your fragment left to right
                replaceFragments(FragmentLeftToRight.getInstance());
                return true;
            }

            if (angle < -45 && angle >= -135) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
                //here open your fragment up to down
                replaceFragments(FragmentUpToDown.getInstance());
                return true;
            }

            if (angle > 45 && angle <= 135) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
                //here open your fragment down to up
                replaceFragments(FragmentDownToUp.getInstance());
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


    });
}

private void replaceFragments(Fragment fragment) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the help but Im just wondering, what do I replace (replaceFragments) with and also when I put my fragment in (FragmentLeftToRight.getInstance()) the .getInstance() becomes invalid.

Comment: Also why is the container Invalid?

Comment: hi@KristoferH the replaceFragments are used to open the fragments which you want to open when someone swipes left and right or up and down to take hime to different views if this is your business requirement otherwise anyways we have the left,right,up and down logic which can be used to do what ever the requirement is. and container is invalid because you are not using the same layout container which i am using since  you are not using the fragment i guess.

Comment: Last question, what about the .getInstance() it became red or am I not suppose to replace the FragmentUpToDown with another fragment?

Comment: .getInstance() is a factory method inside those fragments in my example to get  the fragment instance you can also simply pass 
new FragmentUpToDown()
it will also work.